# How to compare first and last letter of two variables returning false or true

Tags: javascript, string

I want to compare two variables: beast and dish.

The function should return true if the first AND the last letter of beast and dish are the same.

I have 90% of the code. The only problem is when beast or dish is a two word string e.g. "big yeti"

My code:

```
function feast(beast, dish) {
  var beastFirstLetter = beast.charAt(0)
  var beastLastLetter = beast.charAt(-1)
  var dishFirstLetter = dish.charAt(0)
  var dishLastLetter = dish.charAt(-1)

  if (beastFirstLetter === dishFirstLetter && beastLastLetter === dishLastLetter) {
  return true
  } else {
  return false
  }
}
```

Why is feast("brown bear", "bear claw") returning true and not false?

Answer (score 1):

You can't give a negative index to [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt); when you do, you'll always get back `""`.

To get the last character of a string, use `str.charAt(str.length - 1)` or `str.slice(-1)` (since [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) accepts negative indexes, and since `charAt` and `slice` both return strings because JavaScript doesn't have a character type).

Separately, any time you have

```
if (/*..expression with relational operators */) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

it's much simpler and more idiomatic to just write:

```
return /*..expression with relational operators */;
```

since the relational operators (`==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) all return booleans.

Doing both edits:

```js
function feast(beast, dish) {
  var beastFirstLetter = beast.charAt(0)
  var beastLastLetter = beast.charAt(beast.length - 1)
  var dishFirstLetter = dish.charAt(0)
  var dishLastLetter = dish.charAt(dish.length - 1)

  return beastFirstLetter === dishFirstLetter && beastLastLetter === dishLastLetter;
}
console.log(feast("brown bear", "bear claw"));
```

Comment: @user2132380 - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/) is a great JavaScript resource, in this case `charAt` is covered [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is feast("brown bear", "bear claw") returning true and not false?

Because the algorithm is not capturing last letters correctly. `String.charAt(-1)` does not return the last letter but instead an empty string. Simply change:
`var beastLastLetter = beast.charAt(-1)` and `var dishLastLetter = dish.charAt(-1)`

to:

`var beastLastLetter = beast.charAt(beast.length - 1)` and `var dishLastLetter = dish.charAt(dish.length - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing `charAt` with `slice` which can use use a negative index `-1` to remove characters from the right of a string.

```js
function feast(beast, dish) {
  var beastFirstLetter = beast.charAt(0)
  var beastLastLetter = beast.slice(-1)
  var dishFirstLetter = dish.charAt(0)
  var dishLastLetter = dish.slice(-1)

  if (beastFirstLetter === dishFirstLetter && beastLastLetter === dishLastLetter) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

console.log('feast("brown bear", "bear claw"): it shoud be false =>', feast("brown bear", "bear claw"));
```

In fact, `slice(0, 1)` could also be used to get the first character of a string. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for more info.

Comment: That looks interesting. Would var beastLastLetter = beast.slice(-1) store the sliced away character or the body of characters remaining?